# sqlite select query including a "VALUES" in the WHERE clause returns correctly with sqlite but not with python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following SQL query that selects the column 'item' and 'feature' from the table 'my_table' where the pair of columns 'item' and 'other_feature' match some pair of values.

```
select item, feature from my_table 
where (item, other_feature) in (VALUES ('item1', 'A'), ('item1', 'B'));
```

[Here is an example of the dataset used.](https://gist.github.com/Moisan/39682aac5546e3b47995e2c1159fb843)

This query works as expected in the sqlite3 command line interface. However, using the same database, when using the `sqlite3` module in python using the following code I get an error.

```
import sqlite3
query = "select item, feature from my_table where (item, other_feature) in (VALUES ('item1', 'A'), ('item1', 'B'))"
conn = sqlite3.connect("data/my_database.db")
conn.execute(query)
```

I obtain the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Why is this query not working as expected with the python sqlite3 module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try quoting your strings with `"`:

```
query = 'select item, feature from my_table where (item, other_feature) in (VALUES ("item1", "A"), ("item1", "B"))'
```

You also might want to check that the sqlite version

```
select sqlite_version();
```

or in python

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

of you python distribution is not lower than that of your command line interface, and in particular if it is earlier than 3.15.2.

Comment: No luck, I get the same error when quoting with `"` .

Comment: Indeed with `sqlite3.sqlite_version` version 3.13.0 I have this issue and it works fine with 3.16.2. Thank you!